# How to manually set Authorization Header in Google API Explorer

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-apis-explorer

I have made my own custom Auth because For my usecase Google & Fb Login do not suffice.
Have added AuthFilter layer in AppEngine
But I could not figure out any way to add additional Headers like Authorization in Google API Explorer. Any work around ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The APIs Explorer doesn't currently support custom auth types (unless they were input as normal parameters, but this wouldn't be very secure of an API design).